# Unable to boot to ubuntu 20.04 | no brightness control when logging in using `nomodeset`

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, 20.04, intel

I installed ubuntu 20.04 along my windows 10 in my asus tuf gaming (i5 9th gen/gtx1650) laptop.

I was unable to boot to ubuntu initially. Then according to some fixes i saw online, by adding `nomodeset` in grub i was able to successfully login to the system.

But there is no brightenss control and the sound control is not working.
I install nvidia drivers using ubuntu software center, but still if i remove `nomodeset` from grub i am unable to boot and if i add `nomodeset` i am unable to control brightness.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: nomodeset is only used for troubleshooting. If the system boots with nomodeset, it usually means there's a problem with your video card/driver. What model Nvidia? What version driver? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT model # of your ASUS.

Comment: `NVIDIA GTX 1650`
my model is - `fx505gt`
output of the above command i got is - `FX505GT.308`

Comment: As scene in some other answers I tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and now my touchpad and wifi stopped working. External mouse and lan is working fine. And I am able to boot ubuntu without `nomodeset` . But still I don't have sound or brightness control and my touchpad and wifi are also gone. Currently using graphics driver is `nvidia-driver-450 (proprietary,tested)`

Comment: According to https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/, Nvidia driver version 173.1439 is the newest version. Regarding the wi-fi... edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.